# The Documentation review queue shows a “my review history” for <10k rep that does nothing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

I currently have <10k rep, so when I view the [review history page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history), I see this:

[image: my reviews]

However, at the bottom, I have a small link:

> [my review history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history?userId=5244995)

This link displays the same page as above.

---

As [confirmed in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/conversation/viewing-review-history), User [bwoebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153758/bwoebi) (**17.3k** rep) can see all of the reviews:

[image: all of the reviews]

---

## Fixes

1. hide this link for <10k users
2. allow <10k users to see all reviews
3. *<​insert your suggestion here>*

Comment: We're discussing this - I initially just reused the visibility checks that all other review queues use, but as documentation is a collaboration, it does make sense to allow everyone to see all reviews.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Ultimately, you can easily view it in profiles and the specific tags; the only thing missing is the global view, which is mainly useful to detect misbehavior of reviewers (like serial reviewing within few seconds etc.)

Comment: Any update @JarrodDixon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest build allows anyone with access to the queue to see all history (not others' skips, though).