# Documentation review history shows all users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, review-history

I appear to have access to *everyone's* [documentation review history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history) . This didn't used to be the case - is this a bug, or did I not get the memo?

[image]

Comment: The review histories have always been public.  They normally came at a set rep level simply because the queries are expensive; documentation either doesn't (yet) need this restriction as it doesn't have enough data, or someone simply hasn't bothered to set it up yet, most likely.  It's certainly not private information, regardless.  It's always in the data dump for anyone at any rep level.

Comment: @Servy It was definitely filtered last I checked; either it was taken out, or isn't working

Comment: @Servy I had looked on Thursday and saw only my reviews through that page. It indeed changed, it's just a question of whether it was intentional or accidental.

Comment: Like I said, you're treating this like it's confidential information.  It's not.  It's public information.

Comment: @Servy It's not that it's confidential, it's that this is a 10k rep privilege. If they intended to make it available to all, cool! If not, this bug report was a good idea to post.

Comment: Exactly. Again I stress that *this was working before now*

Comment: It’s recently changed. [See my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334337/5244995) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed [last night](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336802/3), allowing registered users to see all review history for the Documentation: Proposed Changes queue.

We felt that more eyes (not just 10K users) on what is being reviewed + how it's being reviewed is better for Documentation, since it's a more public/shared endeavor.

Comment: Next time, can this be introduced via a post of some kind? There seems to be a fair number of recent improvements getting slid into the code base with no warning. Or maybe have a changelog posted somewhere?

Comment: We can try and add them to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange