# Triage History only showing own reviews instead of all reviews

Tags: support, triage

I was looking at the triage history, and was surprised to see only my own reviews. Looking at the bottom of the page there is also a link "my review history" which edits `?userid=[userid]` to the URL. I expect this link to direct me to a page with only my review history, and the normal review history to show a page of all triage reviews made in reverse chronological order. `Documentation: proposed changes` shows this expected behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 10k reputation (which gives access to moderator tools) to see other users' reviews in the review history.  Until you have that privilege, it only shows your own.

Comment: And this requirement is not in place for "Documentation: proposed changes"?

Comment: @Luuklag It's not. That was brought up in a discussion about documentation at some point, but I don't quite recall the reasoning for it. I'll see if I can dig that up. Edit: [Here it is!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336848/documentation-review-history-shows-all-users)